# Android: only 834 devices are supported

Tags: android, flutter

I see on Google Play Console, there are only 834 devices supported for my app.
[image: google play console]
How do I increase the number of supported devices?

I want the app to be available to at least a half of the Android devices (approx. 4000?).

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="com.google.ar.core.depth" android:required="false" />
```

minSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 33

The app uses flutter-unity-widget.

Comment: `How do I increase the number?` Which number?  `More than 4000 are desirable.` ? For what?

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. I updated the sentence.

Comment: Supported for what? Desirable for what? Where did you get that number? Write a decent post please.

Comment: I added an image of Google Play Console where you can see the number of supported devices for the app.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, it's unclear how you calculated the number of compatible devices or why compatibility with 4000 devices should be desirable. Sharing how you determined these numbers would help. Also, it would be interesting to sanity-check that calculation using a clean, minimal project without any dependencies / requirements.

However, the Android developers [Distribution dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards) offers some general advice:

- **Platform version**: When creating a new project using Android Studio's *Create New Project wizard* you should see the amount of devices compatible with your specified minSdkVersion. According to the dashboard, you should also see this in [Reach and devices](https://play.google.com/console/about/reachanddevices/) in your Google Play Console. [apilevels.com](https://apilevels.com/) (updated August 2023) and [statista.com](https://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/180113/umfrage/anteil-der-verschiedenen-android-versionen-auf-geraeten-mit-android-os/) (September 2023) state that your minSdkVersion of 29 (i.e., Android 10) satisfies about 80% of all active Android devices. flutter_unity_widget has a minSdkVersion of 19 in its [Troubleshooting](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget#troubleshooting) section, so you might be able to decrease your minSdkVersion to reach more devices.
- **Screen size/density**: If your app requires specific screen sizes, this decreases the number of compatible devices. The more screen sizes and densities you allow, the more devices you might be able to support.
- **Vulkan or OpenGL**: Since you are using Unity in your project, you might have some requirement on Vulkan or OpenGL version. If you can loosen that requirement to support more versions of Vulkan or OpenGL, more devices might be compatible.